# Why in photoelectric effect the probability of hiting electron is greater for the more tightly bound electron?

Tags: optics, photons, photoelectric-effect

In photoelectric effect the scattered photon have less energy than in Compton effect , in photoelectric effect the photon hit the electron in inner shell but in Compton the photon hit the electron in outer shell.  How that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the K shell electron preferred in the photo electric effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206263/why-is-the-k-shell-electron-preferred-in-the-photo-electric-effect)

Comment: But. i am not satisfied by this the answer

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me a confusion of two experimental set ups.

a) [the phototelectric effect,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html) one of the experimental observations that made quantum mechanical theory inevitable

> *The minimum energy* required to eject an electron from the surface is called the photoelectric work function.

[image: photoelect]

The fact of a minimum energy needed for ejecting electrons from a surface agreed with the necessity of a particle nature, quantization ,  of light and energy levels in materials.

b)The generic term "photoelectric" , i.e. interactions of photons with bound electrons, which is seen in the answer by [Floris](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206263/why-is-the-k-shell-electron-preferred-in-the-photo-electric-effect) in the proposed duplicate.

The K etc states excited are found with x-rays with the appropriate energy for the K etc bound states.

The [Compton](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/comptint.html) effect is not quantized, it is on free electrons, or assumed to be as free; note it is xrays  used in that first Compton experiment. The photoelectric effect is with visible or ultravioelet light, much lower energies.