# Why bound shell for photoelectric effect?

Tags: interactions, photoelectric-effect

***Why does the photoelectric effect occur in the inner shell, Is it possible in the outer shell?***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the K shell electron preferred in the photo electric effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206263/why-is-the-k-shell-electron-preferred-in-the-photo-electric-effect)

Answer (score 0):

Photons can not interact with free electrons to give a photoelectric effect because energy & momentum can not be conserved simultaneously in this system.

Comment: You've never heard of the Compton effect?

Comment: Photons interact with the free electrons in Compton effect.