# K-Shell, Low-Energetic Photons & Photoelectric effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, photoelectric-effect

At low photon energies, the probability of the photoelectric effect to occur increases, but the probability of the photoelectric effect to happen also increases when going towards most inner shells like K shell but inner shells require much more photon energies to be broken, so isn't there a contrast here? How is this EVEN possible?

Comment: I think the answers here are adequate https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206263/why-is-the-k-shell-electron-preferred-in-the-photo-electric-effect ,